# Python script to update single select custom field in jira

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to update a single select custom field (customfield_11104). This field have 5 option 1. None 2. PR Review 3. Production 4. Staging 5. Rejected.  I want to update this field to staging using a python script. Below script showing some error.
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_11104":"Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object."}} Could you please help to update this custom field to staging using python script.

```
from jira import JIRA
import urllib3
import sys
urllib3.disable_warnings()
API_token = 'xxx'
jiraOptions = {'server': 'https://xxx','verify': False}
authedJira = JIRA(jiraOptions, token_auth=API_token,max_retries=0)
#example
ticket = sys.argv[1]
issue = authedJira.issue(ticket)
issue.update(fields={'customfield_11104': [{'value':'Staging'}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the doc [examples](https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html?highlight=update#examples) and your description of your custom field. It seems you are unnecessarily enclosing your dictionary in a list.

It should probably be:

```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_11104': {'value':'Staging'}})
```

Or, as the error message suggests:

```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_11104': {'id':4}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to modify the answer from @tranbi:

For selection fields, you can use either the **text value** of the option, or its **numeric ID**.

If you use the text value, your code will work, but it will break as soon as anyone changes the text of any of the options (e.g., from 'Staging' to 'staging').

The IDs, OTOH, never change.

Also note that the IDs *do not start* with 1. Option IDs are allocated **globally** by Jira (across all custom fields and their contexts), so there are no two options with the same ID.

So, to correct the answer (just tested it  on my Jira Cloud instance):

Updating by option text:

```
payload = json.dumps(
         {'fields': 
             {'customfield_11104': {'value': 'Staging'}}
         })
```

Updating by option ID:

```
    payload = json.dumps(
         {'fields': 
             {'customfield_11104': {'id': '11204'}}
         })
```

Then you perform the update with the payload:

```
issue.update(url, auth, headers, payload=payload)
```